# properties of convergence of sequences of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let {Xn,n=1,2,⋯} and {Yn,n=1,2,⋯} be two sequences of random variables (elements from Xn are independent with elements from Yn). Suppose that we know that Xn converges in probability to X, and Yn converges in probability to Y.
Is (Xn-Yn)^2 converges in probability to (X-Y)^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $Z_i =(X_i, Y_i)$ and $f(x, y)=(x-y)^2$

since $Z_i$ converges in probability, $f$ is continuous, the result is an immediate result of the continuous mapping theorem for random variables:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Comment: there is a direct proof without using the continues map theorem?